# Visual Studio 2015 Preview , While creating Web Projects throwing Unspecified error HRESULT:0x80004005 (E_FAIL)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

I downloaded the VS2015 Preview and tried to create a Web Project.

I am getting the following errors when creating the project itself.

I get a Watson error first 'Unspeciifed error HRESULT:0x80004005 (E_FAIL)' ,

Then When I tried to open the Project Directly from the physical location it is throwing the other error 'Unable to create the Virtual Directory Localhost:5544 ...Error:Filename:redirection.config'

Comment: Problems in beta versions are usual, and it makes not sense to find a general solution for them,because usually there isn't. Make the usual things: install it on another system, try to find a working virtual machine that includes this tool...

Answer (score 0):

I had tried each of the steps recommended and didn't work. So, my last resource was to review the registry to find out if my user was pointing to a temp or cache folder.

Some posts were suggesting to check on `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`; but nothing there. So, I finally found it by going into the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` as recommended by boilers222.

1. Opened registry (CTRL+R, `regedit`, OK)
2. Navigated to
   `KEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders\`
3. Found out the Personal key was pointing to
   `\OurServer\RedirectedFolders\MyName\MyDocuments`
4. Selected the Personal key, right clicked on it, and selected Modify
5. Entered a location pointing to my user's documents file:
   `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\`
6. Clicked OK and closed the registry editor

When I opened Visual Studio and opened my solution, it loaded without the "unable to access the IIS metabase" error.